# Named argument for fish function with argparse

Tags: shell, parsing, arguments, fish

The fish `function` builtin has the option `-a/--argument-names` which allows binding an argument to a name.

Is it still possible to do this while also using the `argparse` builtin? If so, how?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I designed and implemented `argparse`. Yes, technically you can use the `--argument` flag and `argparse` in the same function but doing so makes no sense. The `--argument` option operates completely independently of `argparse` and has no knowledge of flags. Create the following function:

```
function x -a arg1 -a arg2
    set --show arg1 arg2 argv
end
```

Now invoke it thusly: `x --flag val arg`. Notice that `--flag` is bound to `arg1` and `val` is bound to `arg2` and `argv` still contains all of the arguments passed to the function. If your function has flags you shouldn't use `--argument`. If it doesn't then there isn't any point in using `argparse`.

Comment: Ah well. Feature request time.

Comment: @0az How would you expect the two to interact? As I said already if your function recognizes short or long flags you should use `argparse` and not `--argument`. And `--argument` itself isn't really needed in any case. It's just syntactic sugar for doing `set -l arg1 $argv[1]`, `set -l arg2 $argv[2]`, etc. inside the function. Take a look at some of the standard autoloaded functions that use `argparse`; e.g., *alias.fish*.

Comment: To be specific, a feature request for adding positional arguments to argparse. It's just sugar, but it's sugar that encourages usage of more readable names.

Comment: @0az After `argparse` finishes `$argv` has all the non-positional arguments removed; i.e., it will only contain positional arguments. So if giving them meaningful names improves the clarity of your function just do `set -l var_name1 $argv[1]`, etc., after the `argparse` invocation. I'm skeptical that complicating `argparse` in this manner is justified. Especially since you then have to define rules for what happens when the number of positional args don't match the number of var names.